# Easier way to download a string with cookies?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, webclient

Is there an easier way to write this?
I know if i didnt need cookies i could have done

```
var sz = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
```

But i need cookies bc of login data so i am stuck with this instead. Is there a way to make it short like the line above?

```
        request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.CookieContainer = cookie;
        string sz;
        using (var r = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        {
            using(var r2 = (TextReader)new StreamReader(r))
            {
                sz= r2.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777221/c-using-cookiecontainer-with-webclient-class help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Déjà vu... I think I've answered this question before! :-)

Take a look at [Using CookieContainer with WebClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777221/c-using-cookiecontainer-with-webclient-class)