# Screen scrape that bypass older browser detection

Tags: c#, screen-scraping

I am trying in C# to screen scrap two airlines site so I can compare the two fares over many different dates. I manage to do on qua.com but when I try to do it on amadeus.net, I encounter that this site give me a response of

> older browser not supported

So using webbrowser class doesn't work... using httpwebrequest doesnt work also.
So I want to use webclient but because amadeus.net is heavily base on js or something. I do not know where to post url.

Any suggestion?

Edit: webclient.downloadstring also doesn't wort

Comment: Amadeus' website seems to be [using JavaScript to call their own api](http://i.imgur.com/c8wpv2T.png). Find out how to get your access token the same way their website does and you'll have a better solution than scrapping off the info out of their HTML

Comment: Probably, pass a different User-Agent header with your request. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#User_agent_identification, see here for how http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841540/setting-the-user-agent-header-for-a-webclient-request

Comment: Yeah that works, but now the website wants me to accept cookies

Comment: Well, I don't want to get into a detailed comment discussion where I coach you harvesting data from web sites. You need to ask questions on StackOverflow. Be sure to vote up the question and answer I linked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777221/using-cookiecontainer-with-webclient-class, seek and ye shall find, likewise, vote them up.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Navigate overload with the user agent:

```
string useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0" ;
webBrowser.Navigate(url, null, null,useragent) ;
```

An alternative is to use another WebBrowser such as [awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/)

Comment: With Firefox or IE 10 that work for your site, connect to this [url](http://id.furud.net/index.php) to get an accepted user agent string and try it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into passing a fake useragent (from Jodrell) in httpWebrequest, this works but i had to deal with cookies so that can get complicated.
Graffito suggest to overload useragent within a webBrowser but didn't work as it gave me lots of JS loading error, this is because within that website it-self it requires a proper modern browser for it to work.

I found out that my IE itself is a version 9, so i upgraded it IE.11. Then tried Graffito solution again, but that didn't work.

So in the end i thought i might as well update webBrowser to the correct version by following this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612255/regarding-ie9-webbrowser-control)