# c# webclient downloadstring error

Tags: c#, webclient

So I'm attempting to use the WebClient#downloadString(url) and it's not seeming to work, this is the error message:

```
An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code 
Additional information: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
```

I'm not sure why this happens or how to fix it, if anyone could help me out with that than that would be great. My current code is this:

```
 string webData = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://api.predator.wtf/host2ip/?arguments=www.google.com");
```

This code is mainly just for testing and it's not working at all. Anyone have any ideas? I've looked around a bit and can't find any way to fix this error.

Comment: Server has closed the connection, and not WebClient problem

Comment: Is there a specific reason the the server would close the connection? Is there a way I could keep the server open?

Comment: Sometimes you need to set the user-agent header. Some servers are rejecting if user-agent is empty, like your WebClient : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841540/setting-the-user-agent-header-for-a-webclient-request

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you very much @x...

Comment: Jumping in late, but the National Weather Service did that same "block" about a year ago.  Took me a bit to realize that's what they were looking for the user-agent header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set the user-agent header. Some servers are rejecting connection if user-agent is empty:

```
using (var w = new WebClient())
{
    w.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36");
    var s = w.DownloadString("http://api.predator.wtf/host2ip/?arguments=www.google.com");
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: I just move the "answer" from "comments" to "answer"...:=)