# Download Files using C# from https Website

Tags: c#, https, webclient

I'm trying to download a pdf file from https website, but it doesn't work. I'm new to C#, so did some research and found a simple code. Worse, the exception I get is quite generic. Help please.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string file_ = "https://www.nseindia.com/content/circulars/CMPT34469.pdf";
        string path_ = @"E:\RSR\Office\EEP\FileDownloader\output\Hello_World.pdf";

        WebClient wc_ = new WebClient();
        wc_.DownloadFile(file_, path_);
    }
```

The exception:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Comment: `string file_ = "http://`
https?

Comment: Corrected - sorry. The code doesn't work for either.

Comment: please share all information about the exception you get (number, text, inner exception, call stack)

Comment: Do you have to authenticate to download?

Comment: Side note, but there is absolutely no gain in uglifying `FileUrl` to `file_`

Answer (score 5):

The server is checking to see if you're a real user by using your user agent header. It also requires that you specify the mime type you want. This isn't a *general* C# thing, it's just the host you're connecting to (nseindia.com).

This works for me.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string file_ = "https://www.nseindia.com/content/circulars/CMPT34469.pdf";
    string path_ = @"E:\RSR\Office\EEP\FileDownloader\output\Hello_World.pdf";

    WebClient wc_ = new WebClient();
    wc_.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Other");
    wc_.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/pdf");
    wc_.DownloadFile(file_, path_);
}
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11841680/1132334. this host has a peculiar configuration. For example, with the user agent string for IE11 on Windows 8.1, it returns 404 - not found.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string file_ = "https://www.nseindia.com/content/circulars/CMPT34469.pdf";
    string path_ = @"E:\RSR\Office\EEP\FileDownloader\output\Hello_World.pdf";

    WebClient wc_ = new WebClient();
    wc_.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Other");
    wc_.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/pdf");
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
    wc_.DownloadFile(file_, path_);
}
```