# Illegal characters in path while downloading the file from FTP server

Tags: c#

Application was working fine in production server but in past 2 days application is getting "Illegal characters in path" while downloading the file.

Now application is reading the file in the below format for which application is throwing issue :

> [2017-06-10 11:30:09 +1] DEBUG 94 [PickFileService] - File found for
>   download : 52 Oct 03 06:34

```
<a href="https://bytes.com/SimboxDetection-TigoTD_20171003_14_40.csv">https://bytes.com/SimboxDetection-TigoTD_20171003_14_40.csv</a>
```

But the proper file should be :

> [2017-29-09 18:17:11 +1] DEBUG 6 [PickFileService] - File found for
>   download : FB_OnNet_2017-09-29-18-17-04.csv

Could you guys let me know,,what will be the issue?????

Comment: Please, show us the code you are using to download the file. Where are you getting the filename from? What is the exact filename?

Comment: We have absolutely no clue what you are trying to do. What does a HTTPS link have to do with FTP? There are two different protocolls.

Comment: Application is reading the file from FTP server which is having .csv format and then its downloading the file from the FTP server of specific path.

Comment: Yes, but where does this path "<a href="https://bytes.com/..." come from. This is not a FTP path. A FTP path must begin with "ftp://". You cannot download using the FTP protocoll from a non-FTP site. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43165954/880990. Note: This site is about programming. If you are just using an application, this is the wrong site.