# c# set WebClient useragent permanently

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I am using WebClient to send some request to github api.

```
var wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "notempty"); 
wc.Headers.Add("authorization", "basic " + Convert.ToBase64String("user:password"));
var response = wc.DownloadString(url + "/labels");
...
var response = wc.DownloadString(url + "/issues");
```

First I query all labels and then all issues

However on the 2nd DownloadString I get the following exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine
>      at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
>      at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)

I don't get the exception if I set the useragent after first DownloadString. Why is that?

Comment: checkout the following answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/22134980/952310](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22134980/952310)

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18516970/2267478) will be of use.

Comment: so this is a feature? interesting...