# Why am I getting "The server committed a protocol violation Section-ResponseStatusLine" when debugging my web application?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, .net-4.0

I have a .NET 1.1 solution where all projects have been upgraded to .NET 4.0 (VS2010, Windows 7).  To get past my "Unable to start debugging on the web server" problem, I switched my web application property to use VS Development Server instead of IIS.

When debugging the web application, it launches OK.  But I get the above error when I hit a line where I call a web service that's local on my machine.  I've seen stuff about adding useUnsafeHeaderParsing=false, but my web.config doesn't have a sytem.net section.

Is it not able to server the web service as well as the web application simultaneously on the application development server?  Do I need to get it configured correctly to use IIS7?  As a longtime IIS6 user, just looking at it makes my head spin...  although, I do have the site and webservices set up within it, and I am fairly certain it worked at one time.  Gotta love that.

Comment: Have you tried fiddler to see what is happening?  Check this link too.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482715/the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-section-responsestatusline-error

Comment: keywords: visual studio 2013 protocol violation asp.net

Answer (score 36):

This worked for me: Text below is comming from [This CodePlex Post](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/549157/unableplustoplusstartplusdebuggingplusonplustheplu)

> This error usually occurs when you have set up Visual Studio to debug
>   an existing web application running in IIS rather than the built in
>   ASP.NET debug web server. IIS by default listens for web requests on
>   port 80. In this case, another application is already listening for
>   requests on port 80. Typically, the offending application is Skype,
>   which by default takes over listening on ports 80 and 443 when
>   installed. Skype is already occupy the port 80. So IIS is unable to
>   start.
>
> To resolve the issue follow the steps:
>   - Skype -> Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection:
>   - Uncheck *"Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections"*.

Comment: In my case actually it was not Skype but hotspot shield (a free VPN) software was running in background quitting that software resolved my issue.

Comment: Holy moly.  The idea of Visual Studio and Skype having overlap would have never crossed my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Its due to Skype has taken default `Port 80 or 443` and Default website is stopped.
to solve this issue, close Skype, `[Start]` Default Website from IIS, (and start skype again if you want.)

Answer (score 0):

you might also try doing an IIS reset