# C#: HttpClient, The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine

Tags: c#, wpf, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using the [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) class to communicate to a web service in my WPF application.

When I make consecutive GET requests on the same connection, everything works fine.  However, when I make consecutive PUT/PATCH requests on the same connection, the first request executes accurately and I receive a response but the second request does not include the body in the request and I receive the infamous error of "The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine".

My requests do complete successfully if I manually close the connection after every request by adding **Connection: close** to the header.  This "solution" is a bad pattern and performance will not scale appropriately.

Below is a debranded version of a list of my TCP Stream Output from the requests being sent:

**Wireshark: Follow TCP Stream Output**

```
GET /domain/api/tenant/current/object?objectName=Lizbot HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json

    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 50
    {"Data":[{"Id":123,"ObjectName":"Lizbot","Date":null}],"Errors":[]}

PATCH /domain/api/tenant/current/object/123 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 50
{"Id":123,"ObjectName":"Lizbot","Date":null}

    HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    {"Data":null,"Errors":[]}

PATCH /domain/api/tenant/current/object/123/otherObject HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

    HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request</b>
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
    Connection: close
    Content-Length: 311
```

Notice that the second PATCH is missing the object it's supposed to patch with.  If I change the order of the PATCHing, the second PATCH is still missing its object.

This error appears to be common with a few known solutions which I have tried.  They consist of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2482730/1403925) which involves setting the useUnsafeHeaderParsing property to **TRUE** and setting the Keep-Alive property to **FALSE** in the Web.Config.  I also tried the solution of setting these properties in this manner shown below:

```
 ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 2;
 ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

None of these solutions worked.  It should be noted that when using the Http Debugging proxy tool, Fiddler, to capture these requests, I don't receive any errors.

So what I am asking for is if anyone knows a good solution to alleviate this error so I can make multiple requests in a connection without losing the body of an update.  If more details are needed, I am happy to supply them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The underlying problem is that the PATCH response includes content within the body of the response.  Ensure that the server does not send content when sending a 204 No Content.

Comment: Thank you! I am accepting this answer because, although mine will stop the error from being thrown, this ensures I don't have errors TO throw.

Comment: Although I agree that sending 204 with a body is a protocol violation, HttpClient can handle this situation with without any problem.  As can self-hosted web api.  Maybe IIS messing things up.

Answer (score 10):

After much debugging and reading, I realized I was trying to edit the Web.Config file of the WPF application instead of the app.config file!

So if you drop this code in the **app.config** file at the root of the configuration tag for a WPF application, it fixes the problem.

```
<system.net>
<settings>
<httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing = "true"/>
</settings>
</system.net>
```