# Submit form using HttpClient in C#

Tags: c#, httpclient, html-agility-pack, httpresponse

I'm getting the website form by htmlagilitypack, setting the form variable and trying to submit the form. Everything looks that is working fine, but the response from the form submit is null.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string urlAddress = "mywebsite";

        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(urlAddress);

        // Post link
        var post = doc.GetElementbyId("post").GetAttributeValue("href", "");

        doc = web.Load(post);

        // get the form
        var form = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//form[@class='picker']");

        // get the form URI
        string actionValue = form.Attributes["action"]?.Value;
        System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(actionValue);

        // Populate the form variable
        var formVariables = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        formVariables.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id", "ho"));
        var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formVariables);

        // submit the form
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = client.PostAsync(uri, formContent);

    }
```

Does anyone know why my variable response is null?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting a response, and if you are, what does it say in the developer console?

Comment: It says: Id = 3, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"

Comment: @user6824563, you have to `await` the `Task` returned from `PostAsync`

Comment: How can I do it? I'm running everything inside my main function

Comment: @user6824563 show the main function. That way a suggestion could be provided.

Comment: var response = client.PostAsync(uri, formContent).Result;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`HttpClient.PostAsync` return a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` so normally it would need to be awaited. As you are using it in main method you would have to get the result from the task

```
var response = client.PostAsync(uri, formContent).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Or the simpler

```
var response = client.PostAsync(uri, formContent).Result;
```

In both cases response would be an instance of `HttpResponseMessage`. You can inspect that instance for HTTP status and the content of the response.

If using .net core you can even use an async Main method like

```
static async Task Main(string[] args) {

    //..code removed for brevity

    var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, formContent);
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    //...
}
```

Comment: I changed to client.PostAsync(uri, formContent).Result But it was caught in Exception:  InnerException {"The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine"} System.Exception {System.Net.WebException}

Comment: @user6824563 you're going to have to check what causes that error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496451/c-httpclient-the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-section-responsestatu

Comment: Can it be something related to the website that I'm doing it?

Comment: Looks that way. that error is usually associated with a server side error

Comment: Then your question is basically how to search/scrape craigslist using htmlagilitypack.

Comment: @user6824563 A suggestion would be to use httpclient to both get and post to the site. Enable cookies in the client in case the site depends on it. There are many reason that can cause that error. But that is too much to cover here.

Comment: I'm trying to automated the posting in craigslist. Do mean httpclient to get the URI and formContent? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. read up on how to use HttpClient. There are a few options available

Comment: When I start looking for some solutions httpagility seemed the best option

Comment: @user6824563 what I mean is to use httpclient to download the HTML then parse it with agility pack and then post with httpclient. That way the client if configure properly would hold on to cookies.

Comment: Hum... I implemented the same code in asp.net instead of C# console application and it gives me another error: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Comment: Found the problem... I needed to add client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false; It returned me the response. I know this topic is getting too big, but how can I get the html response of the new page after POST? I couldn't find it in the response

Comment: @user6824563 I updated the answer. You should take some time and read up on how to use httpclient

Answer (score 3):

You are missing .`Result` in your `PostAsync`. Simply, change the line to:

```
var response = client.PostAsync(uri, formContent).Result;
```

`.Result` however, runs the tasks synchronously. It returns `AggregateException` if there is an exception making it slightly difficult to debug.

If you are using Visual Studio 2017 Update 15.3 or above and C# 7.1 however, there is support for  `aysnc` `main` now.

You can modify your code as follows:

```
static async Task Main()
{
    string urlAddress = "mywebsite";

        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(urlAddress);

        // Post link
        var post = doc.GetElementbyId("post").GetAttributeValue("href", "");

        doc = web.Load(post);

        // get the form
        var form = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//form[@class='picker']");

        // get the form URI
        string actionValue = form.Attributes["action"]?.Value;
        System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(actionValue);

        // Populate the form variable
        var formVariables = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        formVariables.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id", "ho"));
        var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formVariables);

        // submit the form
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, formContent);
}
```

This will help you to `await` the `async` task. In case you get any exception, you would receive the actual exception rather than `AggregateException`.

It is important to note that C# 7.1 currently is currently not enabled by default. To enable the 7.1 features, you would need to change the language version setting for your project.

Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1#async-main) for more details.