# Protocol violation using Github api

Tags: c#, .net, api, github

I'm getting data from Github for my application.
The first 2 OAuth steps are ok, but in the third I got the following error:
"the server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine ERROR"
This is my code:

```
protected String WebRequest(string url)
    {
        url += (String.IsNullOrEmpty(new Uri(url).Query) ? "?" : "&") + "access_token=" + _accessToken;
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
                return responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }
```

The program goes in exception after using the StreamReader object, that returns me the error.
If I follow these instructions [The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482715/the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-section-responsestatusline-error) , the error turns into "403 forbidden".
When Github used api V2, different from now, there was no problem with this code.
So, can't be a .NET limitation but something connected with Github server.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm running into the same problem, but I've also got some mixed up responses (different threads, request 1 has also the response from request 2)...

Comment: Also getting the same error here. Urgh :(

Answer (score 18):

You need to set UserAgent like this:

```
webRequest.UserAgent = "YourAppName";
```

Otherwise it will give `The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine` error.

Comment: Thanks a lot... Have been looking to resolve this issue all over the web.

Comment: I've been looking for this for hours, I thought it was some keepalive issue. Thanks for this!