# Exception on uploadString()

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm having some trouble dealing with the (in)famous exception "The server commited a protocol violation", I'm trying to send a XML string to a given ip address-port and everything seems to be tip-top but this nasty exception is getting on my nerves, I read some fixes like the config file but that did not work, I'm no expert in C# so I guess there is some gruesome error lingering here somewhere, any help would be appreciated!

```
      string xml = "<Login services=\"NetPage\"/>\n" +
                   "<PageRequest pager=\"2;22\" system_id=\"18\"/>";
       string url = new UriBuilder("http", ipAddress, 3700).ToString();

        using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                client.UploadString(url, xml);
            }
            catch(WebException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

Comment: What does the code look like which handles the request?   the error message indicates that the problem is on your server.

Comment: Oh, that will be a hard problem then... it's a proprietary embedded device, I tested the xml command on postui and it worked so I'm trying to code it now in the application

Comment: Several possible solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2482730/4267590

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd do is set the HTTP content type correctly before calling upload.  Servers often get unhappy when they get unexpected content.

```
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/xml");
client.UploadString(url, xml);
```