# "Protocol violation" when using a specific language code in URI

Tags: c#, rest, get, dotnet-httpclient

We have a REST API which maps third-party proprietary language codes (in the `en-US` format) into language codes that our own system recognises. The REST API's route is

```
~/v1/languages/mappings/{foreignLanguageCode} [GET]
```

We receive these third-party language codes and send them to our own API using an instance of `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`.

This is working perfectly well for many language codes but when passed `ko-US` the request doesn't even get sent - the HttpClient object throws the exception

> An error occurred while sending the request.

The inner exception - a `WebException` - says

> The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine

The exception also contains

> Source: "System"
>   Status: ServerProtocolViolation
>   StackTrace:
>     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>       at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

The URI at this point is

```
https://www.example.com/api/v1/languages/mappings/ko-US/
```

I've tried it with and without that trailing slash: no difference. We can send many other language codes to the same API without any problem.

Can anyone explain why this particular URI causes this exception?

Comment: Is the server crashing or emitting any diagnostics?  You may have to sniff the wire to gain sufficient clues what is going on with that.

Comment: The request isn't being sent, the server isn't being hit; there's nothing on the wire to sniff.

Comment: > The server committed a protocol violation

Comment: It's possible the client is lying because it's really had some internal error of some kind, but the only way to know that is to debug it.

Comment: I've just checked with Fiddler and no request was sent to the expected URI - not just that specific path but the server.

Comment: Is it possibly related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482715/the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-section-responsestatusline-error)?

Comment: Your code is running in a server context?

Answer (score 0):

*Answering my own question...*

I can't really explain why but this solved the problem:

```
myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
```

I added that immediately before sending the request, so the working code looks like this:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
```