# System.Net.WebException: 'The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine'

Tags: c#, .net, http, httpwebrequest, iot

I'm trying to contact an HTTP endpoint used to remotely control a smart strip. Everything done locally in my LAN, and i figured out using an HTTP proxy, that calls are done directly to the strip if the client device is connected to the same WLAN network.

I tried to call the endpoint using Postman and did work like a charm. It just took me to copy the proxy-intercepted body and make a POST.

Now I'm trying to make the same call from some C# code, and I'm getting the exception shown in the question title.

I found [another post here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482715/the-server-committed-a-protocol-violation-section-responsestatusline-error) that shows a way to solve this by changing something server-side, which is not an option in my case. Any ideas on how can I solve this?

I already tried to include all the headers Postman generates automatically, but nothing did help.

Also using different libraries to achieve http communication (RestSharp, native WebRequest) i obtain always the same result.

Comment: Please share with us your current  implementation.

Comment: That's a pretty standard implementation of the HttpClient, nothing new or strange. I'm following the official docs, so I expect it to work like other times before.