# Download pdf programmatically

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf, download, filestream

How can I download a PDF and store to disk using vb.NET or C#?

The URL (of the PDF) has some rediection going on before the final PDF is reached.

I tried the below but the PDF seems corrupted when I attempt to open locally,

```
Dim PdfFile As FileStream = File.OpenWrite(saveTo)
Dim PdfStream As MemoryStream = GetFileStream(pdfURL)
PdfStream.WriteTo(PdfFile)
PdfStream.Flush()
PdfStream.Close()
PdfFile.Flush()
PdfFile.Close()
```

Comment: Can you show the GetFileStream() function as well?

Comment: There's no need to call Flush() if you're going to call Close().

Comment: Is the pdf itself corrupt? The code I posted works for the IRS provided pdf. Other setup I can think of is to use the WebClients DownloadData method and writing the byte[] to disk then.

Comment: Well, the pdf size is 4kb so it's definetely not downloaded properly.

Comment: Ok, the problem seems to be the redirection. If I hard code the end url (the url of the pdf after redirection completes) then it works (using downloaddata method).

Trouble is how do I ensure that the document is downloaded after redirection completes??

Comment: The initial url is:

http://www.blahblah.com/NLAAPI.dll/GetObject?ObjectID=34972180

And after a second or two it redirects to:

http://www.blahblah.com/PDFs/BRABB39.PDF

Comment: If its a script based redirect you will probably have to do some html parsing or something to extract the location its redirecting to.

Comment: Ok, so I looked at the contents of the requested url and it is basically a login page. When I browse the link with my broswer I do not get prompted for login because of a cookie, but I guess requesting the page through this code does not take into account the cookies on my machine.

So...

Is there a way to attach the cookie to webclient request?

Or

Can I (after posting the crdentials programmtically) then somehow get the resulting HttpWebResponse saved to a file??

Many thanks.

Comment: Using CookieContainer with WebClient class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777221/using-cookiecontainer-with-webclient-class and apparently the WebClient class follows redirections: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/csharp/70511872-c3aa-4e92-a7d7-dd4b09881af5/make-the-webclient-class-follow-redirects-and-get-target-url.aspx although I couldn't find that in the MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 24):

You can try to use the WebClient (System.Net namespace) class to do this which will avoid any stream work on your side.

The following C# code grabs an IRS form and saves it to C:\Temp.pdf.

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf", @"C:\Temp.pdf");
}
```

Comment: Tried that, opening pdf I get....
"Adobe Reader could not open file because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged blah blah"

Comment: GetFileStream function:
Protected Function GetFileStream(ByVal URL As String) As MemoryStream
 Dim _url As String = URL
 Dim _wb As WebClient = New WebClient
 Dim myBuffer() As Byte
 Dim _str As MemoryStream = Nothing
 Try
 myBuffer = _wb.DownloadData(_url)
 _str = New MemoryStream(myBuffer)
 Catch ex As Exception
 _str = Nothing
 End Try
 Return _str
End Function

Comment: This can work. and make sure u set security permission to IISUSER if you are putting ur code for web page.

Answer (score 7):

You can also try the following code sample to download pdf files

```
 Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf"; 
 Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Test_PDF.pdf"); 
 Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Files/Test_PDF.pdf")); 
 Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1):

How might you be able to use client.downloadfile when the URL is pointing a "showdocument.aspx" page.

Example:
https://gaming.nv.gov/modules/showdocument.aspx?documentid=246