# C#: How to make HttpWebRequest mimic the Web Browser control

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I've used several `HttpWebRequest`'s in the past but they've all been used to login into a site.

I was wondering how does one make the `WebRequest` mimic a `WebBrowser` as in once you're logged in, navigate to a new page, maybe perform an action there, then go to a different page?

I've researched a little about this before and I think it might involve using the prior request's cookies or something.

My question is how do I (I'm assuming) get the cookies from the previous session, then navigate to a page, or complete an action as if we were still on the last request if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `HttpWebRequest` has a Cookies property and `HttpWebResponse` has a `CookieContainer` property.

you record the cookies from the container, and add them to the next request.

you may also need to set the HTTP `referrer` header field on the request object.

**EDIT :**
this will still not get you mimicking a web browser. things like JavaScript will not work/run.  and you won't have a DOM to work against.

Comment: No.  Its just a strongly typed collection.. Pull up the object browser in VS and take a look at it.  It's very straight-forward.

Comment: @Boo: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972643/how-to-use-cookies-with-httpwebrequest

Comment: Meh, it didnt work. I have my first httpwebrequest set up and created the cookie container. And this is my second httpwebrequest but I dont think anything happened: 

            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://twitter.com/#!/who_to_follow");
            httpWebRequest2.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse2 = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest2.GetResponse();
            StreamReader stream2 = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse2.GetResponseStream());

Comment: @user: You've exhausted my knowledge of the subject. I've used `CookieContainer` with some success in the past on other sites, and it seems to have worked. Are you sure that Twitter is sending a cookie? If you want to use the cookies from a previous session, you need to persist that cookie somehow (write it to disk, save it in memory, etc.), and then get it back from that storage before the next request.