# POST Data with https not work

Tags: c#, winforms, post, webclient

I'm try to Login this website and Get Cookies from Headers but it not work. So here is my code

If login success then fshare_userid must be have value 2312158

```
CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();

        // Set Cookie

        string url = "https://www.fshare.vn/login.php";
        string parameters = "login_useremail=nguoivodanhbtallshare@yopmail.com&login_password=123456&url_refe=http://www.fshare.vn/";

        // create a request
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
        WebRequest.Create(url); request.KeepAlive = false;
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        request.Method = "POST";

        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(parameters);

        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
        request.CookieContainer = cookie;
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        foreach (Cookie c in cookie.GetCookies(response.ResponseUri))
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += "Name : " + c.Name + "\n";
            richTextBox1.Text += "Value : " + c.Value + "\n\n";
        }

        webBrowser1.DocumentText = responseString;
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Use this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972643/how-to-use-cookies-with-httpwebrequest)

```
   CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(...);
    httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
```

Then you reuse this CookieContainer in subsequent requests:

```
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(...);
    httpWebRequest2.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
```