# Copy cookies between request and response

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

```
using (HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)templateRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        header = httpWebResponse.Cookies;
```

That is my response's cookies but here is my request

```
HttpWebRequest templateRequest = base.GetTemplateRequest("https://apps.runescape.com/runemetrics/profile/profile?activities=20");

templateRequest.CookieContainer = ???????????
```

Now how do I take my cookies from the response to the request?

I've tried

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

foreach(Cookie cookie in header)
{
    cookies.Add(cookie);
}
templateRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
```

but it didn't work :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use cookies with HttpWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972643/how-to-use-cookies-with-httpwebrequest)

Comment: @GSerg Nono because the httpwebresponse doesn't return a cookiecontainter :(

Comment: No, but the request object takes one and stores the resulting cookies in the container. The accepted answer on the question GSerg linked to demonstrates as much.

Comment: And yes, it does seem like bad design on Microsoft's part, but that's the way it is.

Comment: The method linked by GSerg is the good one in this context (WebRequest). Discard methods that try to add Cookies in other, extravagant, ways. The CookieContainer can be stored and re-assigned to a WebRequest when needed.