# Get/Set cookie with WebClient

Tags: c#, cookies, webclient

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using CookieContainer with WebClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777221/using-cookiecontainer-with-webclient-class)

Is there any way to get/set cookies with WebClient in C# .net 2.0? (It doesn't seem to be in the MSDN documentation).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777221/c-using-cookiecontainer-with-webclient-class

Comment: That seems to show how to set the cookie, but not how to get it....

Comment: First you need CookieContainer to save the cookie. Then you can use the same thing to read it, it has a GetCookies method.

Comment: I see. Thank you. (Still wonder why there isn't a "native" method...seems like a no-brainer to put cookie support in)