# Using uTorrent Web API via .NET

Tags: c#, .net, token, asp.net-web-api, utorrent

I'm trying to get list of torrents from uTorrent using [Web API](http://www.utorrent.com/community/developers/webapi). Getting required token goes O.K.:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient() { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, pass) };
StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(client.OpenRead("http://localhost:" + port + "/gui/token.html"));
string token = Reader.ReadToEnd();
token = token.Split('>')[2].Split('<')[0]; 
// token is now something like 3LemfrO_-A-SNBXlnQ2QcQWTYydx7qOqKb1W1S54JJW74Ly3EYGgu0xQSU4AAAAA
```

But when I try to use it to get list of torrents:

```
Reader = new StreamReader(client.OpenRead("http://localhost:" + port + "/gui/?list=1&token=" + token));
```

all I get is "Error 400 Bad request".

I've tried to get token manually. In browser page "http://localhost:30303/gui/?list=1&token=3LemfrO_-A-SNBXlnQ2QcQWTYydx7qOqKb1W1S54JJW74Ly3EYGgu0xQSU4AAAAA" opens as it should, but in C# with the same link without any variables I still get error 400.
The interesting part is that if switch off token authentication WebClient load page perfectly with and without

```
"&token=3LemfrO_-A-SNBXlnQ2QcQWTYydx7qOqKb1W1S54JJW74Ly3EYGgu0xQSU4AAAAA"
```

but token auth enabled by default, so my and any app should use it.
And yes, WebRequest/HttpWebRequest didn't help also.

P.S. sorry for my English, I was never able to make it work right

Comment: Most likely an encoding issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have to save the cookie from the request

```
Classes.CookieAwareWebClient client = new Classes.CookieAwareWebClient() { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("shehab", "shehab") };
StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(client.OpenRead("http://localhost:" + "8080" + "/gui/token.html"));
string token = HtmlRemoval.StripTagsRegexCompiled(Reader.ReadToEnd());
MessageBox.Show(token);

Reader = new StreamReader(client.OpenRead("http://localhost:" + "8080" + "/gui/?list=1&token=" + token));
MessageBox.Show(Reader.ReadToEnd());
```

and for the cookie aware class go to the following link([Using CookieContainer with WebClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777221/c-using-cookiecontainer-with-webclient-class)) as web client doesn't support cookies.

Answer (score 1):

You should save cookies from request

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:" + port + "/gui/token.html");
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
(request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = cookies;
```

And then use it in every other request to uTorrent when using the same token:

```
request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:" + port + "/gui/?list=1&token=" + token);
(request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = cookies;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple 3-step suggestion:

1. When you use your browser with the token, use [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to analyze the HTTP traffic between the server and browser.
2. Open up your C# app and use Fiddler2 to analyze the HTTP traffic between the server and your app.
3. Compare the HTTP requests and responses for the browser with the requests and responses for the C# app. If you see a significant difference, there is a good chance that could be the problem.

Comment: I've tried. I've tried hard. It looks like WebClient and WebRequest change field Set-Cookie and Opera(which I use) do not. I'll check this direction tomorrow. Thanks a lot

Comment: I think the set-cookie field is part of a response from the server. Maybe the server wants your WebClient to set a cookie, and then your WebClient should send the cookie back in all future HTTP requests. Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks, that's it, i found the problem!