# Need a way to select a dropdown's options 1 by 1 to parse data

Tags: c#

I have a system that basically copies data from other databases to my own SQL Server so I can format the data to suit my needs. That data is used to populate dropdowns to end up with a variable can return the rows I want to show to the user.

All of the databases I've encountered up to now had a logical way the data of the dropdowns was stored. But now I have one that is different and not logical.

What I want to do is use the existing website that provides a somewhat logical dropdown itself  to get the data I need. That dropdown fills a multiple selection dropdown after a selection.

I want to select each option in the first dropdown and then read the data it puts in the second multiple selection dropdown. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How is the multiple selection dropdown populated by the first? Postback? Ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you essentially want to do is web scraping. In a similar project, this is what I did:

1. Use the available objects in .NET that can send http requests and can receive http responses. In my case, I used WebClient:

   ```
       byte[] response;
       using (var client = new WebClient())
       {
           try
           {
               response = client.UploadValues(URL, "POST", postData);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               // Log error here                  
           }
       }
   ```
2. See the postData? This is a `NameValueCollection` that contains the data that is sent by the page when you do a POST. Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or a similar tool to find out what data needs to be included. If the page uses .NET web forms, you may have to do something special for the __VIEWSTATE, like do a sample request and get the __VIEWSTATE value from there. Here's a sample for postData:

   ```
       var postData = new NameValueCollection();
       postData.Add("__EVENTTARGET",  "");
       postData.Add("__EVENTARGUMENT", "");
       postData.Add("__VIEWSTATE", "");
   ```
3. Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to easily "parse" the response that you get when you post. Using Xpath, you will be able to get the new items in the second dropdown.

   ```
       var doc = new HtmlDocument();
       doc.Load(new MemoryStream(requestBytes));
       return doc;
   ```

Comment: I've got it working now but I keep getting a session timeout. Do you know what could be causing it?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting it?

Comment: When i send the post with the event target filled. I get response: 
Your current session has expired. Please click below to begin again on restart.

Comment: Does your post data contain everything that should be sent over?

Comment: i've got all the data from fiddler. But when i fill the eventtarget it gives that response

Comment: I've taken a look at the site and it looks like cookie information needs to be sent over as well. Take a look at this if you're using a WebClient: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777221/using-cookiecontainer-with-webclient-class

Comment: I still can get it right, what i do is:
I do a request to the URL, from the URL is get the VIEWSTATE and the __EVENTVALIDATION. Then i make a new request (WebClient) with the following postdata

Comment: postData.Add("__EVENTTARGET", "LinkBtn_studentsets");
        postData.Add("__EVENTARGUMENT", "");
        postData.Add("__VIEWSTATE", viewstate);
        postData.Add("__EVENTVALIDATION", EVENTVALIDATION);
        postData.Add("tLinkType", "staff");
        postData.Add("dlFilter", "DEM/DL");
        postData.Add("tWildcard", "");
        postData.Add("lbWeeks", "t");
        postData.Add("RadioType", "individual;staffbydayurl;staffbydayreport");

Comment: But the response still geive back all the data drom the second field. Not filtered data.

Comment: Have you tried other values for `dlFilter` and the results are the same? Try `DBSV` and see if that works fine.

Comment: Yes, but the results are the same, or a error. I tried lots of things, but it wont do the postback. The only element i can change is the Wildcard element, by adding filter to the query.

Comment: What is the dlFilter value when you got the error? What is the error?

Comment: it redirects to swsError.aspx?aspxerrorpath=%2f2011sm2nl%2fDefault.aspx that is when i set the eventtarget or a wrong dlFilter value.

Comment: Change your `__EVENTTARGET` to `dlFilter` and see how it goes.

Comment: postData.Add("__EVENTARGUMENT", "LinkBtn_studentsets");
postData.Add("__EVENTTARGET", "dlFilter");
postData.Add("dlFilter", "DBSV");
response is the same error
postData.Add("__EVENTARGUMENT", "LinkBtn_studentsets");
        postData.Add("dlFilter", "DBSV");
Response: all the fields, not filterd
When i do a postback from the site, Fiddler tells me: __EVENTTARGET=dlFilter&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDw,.......&__EVENTVALIDATION=...........%2F&tLinkType=studentsets&dlFilter=DEM%2FDL%2FA&tWildcard=&lbWeeks=t&RadioType=individual%3Bstudentsetbydayurl%3Bstudentsetbydayreport

Comment: That last one was what I was getting as well. That resulted to an error?

Comment: an error, but when i replace the acsii %2F to / then it returns the full field. 
When I set the eventtarget to dlFilter it returns the default page, not the schedule page.