# WCF Authentication Service Proxy - CookieContainer not available

Tags: wcf, authentication, wcf-security

I have enabled the ASP.Net authentication service, as recommended by msdn. I am then attempting to use the service via a console app or winforms app (by adding a service reference to my local WCF service). I am doing custom authentication and transport security (so I am handling the `AuthenticationService.Authenticating` event in my `Global.asax` which works fine).

The authentication itself works fine, but the proxy created by adding the Service Reference does not include the `CookieContainer` property. This is obviously a problem when I try to pass the cookie token to subsequent services which require authentication.

Also, in the following client code, the `IsLoggedIn()` returns false, I'm guessing this is related to no cookie container being present.

```
ServiceReference1.AuthenticationServiceClient client = 
                  new ServiceReference1.AuthenticationServiceClient();
bool isLoggedIn = client.Login("test", "test", "", true); //returns TRUE
bool check = client.IsLoggedIn(); //returns FALSE
```

Here is my web.config on the service:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <authenticationService enabled="true"
           requireSSL = "false"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService"
          behaviorConfiguration="AuthenticationServiceTypeBehaviors">
        <endpoint contract="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="userHttps"
          bindingNamespace="http://asp.net/ApplicationServices/v200"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="userHttps" allowCookies="true">
          <!--<security mode="Transport" />-->
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AuthenticationServiceTypeBehaviors">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

EDIT: Something else I should add, I did a Fiddler session of the service calling the `Login` method, and the cookie is being set and sent back to the client. But what am I supposed to do with no CookieContainer?

Comment: Did you look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777221/using-cookiecontainer-with-webclient-class ?

Comment: That post is not applicable to my issue. Thank you for the idea though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, when adding a Service Reference (.Net 3.5+) to a WCF service on a client, the proxy class derives from `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`. This class does not have a CookieContainer property (because the ClientBase supports non-HTTP protocols that have no concept of cookies).

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2011/11/managing-cookies-in-wcf-client.html

I could add a Web Reference instead, which would use the .Net 2.0 proxy class (and has `CookieContainer` property exposed) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx. But I will most likely revisit my approach entirely and use custom headers and service behaviors to accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 2):

> When this option is enabled the client will make sure all cookies received from a given web
>   service are stored and properly sent on each subsequent request in a transparent fashion.
>   But there is a catch: the cookie is only handled in the conversation with one web service.
>   What if you need to send the same cookies to different web services?

If you need to send the same cookies to multiple services, read this article: http://megakemp.wordpress.com/2009/02/06/managing-shared-cookies-in-wcf/

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the binding to allow cookies.

```
<system.ServiceModel>
     <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding allowCookies="true">
     </bindings>
```

Comment: Cookies will only be passed to the service that created them. Are you trying to send it to a different service?

Comment: No, there is no different service, I'm just trying to get the cookies into a `CookieContainer`

Comment: Yes, it does allow `client.IsLoggedIn()` to return true, but doesn't give me access to the cookie itself to persist it.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin I am also stuck at the same point.. did you manage to find a solution? I am calling authenticationServiceWCF from a WP7 code behind and trying to get the cookie, but in vain.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin I did see that, but I am calling aync methods on AuthenticationService WCF. If I use it like this, how can I get the response object? Other doubt is ; in example it is shown as setting some value to cookie and I dont have control of the authentication process as I am using ASP.net authentication.[[Using WP7 and trying for ASP.NET authentication using AuthenticationService WCF Service]]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to access the cookie container for the underlying channel like this:

```
var cookieManager = client.InnerChannel.GetProperty<IHttpCookieContainerManager>();
cookieManager.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie(....));
```

For the above manager to be present, you need to set AllowCookies to true, e.g.:

```
<system.ServiceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding allowCookies="true">
    </bindings>
```