# WebClient CookieContainer works well in .NET 4.0+ but not in earlier versions

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I am developing an application that uses WebClient. I have this class that extends basic WebClient functionality:

```
public class WebClientEx : WebClient
{
    private CookieContainer _cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = _cookieContainer;
            (request as HttpWebRequest).AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            (request as HttpWebRequest).Timeout = 10000;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

I use WebClientEx to login to site and to request some information. It works well for 4.0 and 4.5, but it doesn't work in earlier versions such as 3.5, 3.0 etc. I added some debug code and in early versions it says that there are 0 cookies in cookie container, while 4.0+ says that there are two cookies, as it should be.

So the reason is probably that early versions of .NET Framework have *some problems with storing cookies in the cookie container*. How to fix that?

Comment: The answer to your question may be found here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777221/using-cookiecontainer-with-webclient-class

Comment: Anyone will help or I must use simpler solution without extending WebClient?

Comment: My tests show this class is working as expected.  Perhaps you could explain a little more as to why you believe it is not working.

Answer (score 5):

I have confirmed the behaviour is different in .NET 3.5 compared to .NET 4.0.  Is used the following code to test:

```
Uri sourceUri = new Uri(@"http://www.html-kit.com/tools/cookietester/");
WebClientEx webClientEx = new WebClientEx();
webClientEx.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webClientEx.UploadString(sourceUri, "cn=MyCookieName&cv=MyCookieValue");
var text = webClientEx.DownloadString(sourceUri);
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes((text))));
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div").Single(n => n.InnerText.StartsWith("\r\nNumber of cookies received:"));
Debug.Assert(int.Parse(node.InnerText.Split(' ')[4]) == 1);
```

Of course, this doesn't answer your question; but I can see no reason why there is a difference in behaviour other than to say maybe it was fixed in .NET 4.0 and the fix hasn't be put into .NET 3.5 or prior versions.

I tried a similar thing with `HttpWebRequest` and had the same problem (works in 4, but not prior):

```
HttpWebRequest webreq = ((HttpWebRequest) (WebRequest.Create(sourceUri)));
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

var postdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("cn=MyCookieName&cv=MyCookieValue");

webreq.CookieContainer = cookies;
webreq.Method = "POST";
webreq.ContentLength = postdata.Length;
webreq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

Stream webstream = webreq.GetRequestStream();
webstream.Write(postdata, 0, postdata.Length);
webstream.Close();

using (WebResponse response = webreq.GetResponse())
{
    webstream = response.GetResponseStream();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(webstream))
    {
        String responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes((responseFromServer))));
        var node =
            doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div").Single(n => n.InnerText.StartsWith("\r\nNumber of cookies received:"));
        Debug.Assert(int.Parse(node.InnerText.Split(' ')[4]) == 1);
    }
}
```

So, there seems to be a problem with `HttpWebRequest` (which `WebClient` uses).  This might be new because I've seen people use code like this before 4.0 was released (maybe prior to 3.50 and they say it worked.

If it's urgent, I would suggest contacting Microsoft Support.  If you have an MSDN license the following link will detail how to make a support request with the included MSDN support tickets: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/bb266240.aspx  If you don't have MSDN you can contact Support as detailed here: https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?Gprid=8291&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn

if it's less urgent, then you could probably log the issue at http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio to see if you get a response with workarounds.

Comment: Maybe I will just try other, simpler solution (so bad I should use bad solutions because of bugs). If I have spare time I will post a bug but I think they know about it. No one more will anser IMO so I will give you +50...

Answer (score 2):

I just created a basic IHttpHandler to test this class and it appears to work.

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="CookieTest" %>

using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

public class CookieTest : IHttpHandler
{
    public class WebClientEx : WebClient
    {
        private CookieContainer _cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
            if (request is HttpWebRequest)
            {
                (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = _cookieContainer;
                (request as HttpWebRequest).AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                (request as HttpWebRequest).Timeout = 10000;
            }
            return request;
        }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext ctxt)
    {
        ctxt.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        String cmd = ctxt.Request["cmd"];
        if (cmd == "set")
        {
            ctxt.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("test", "test"));
            ctxt.Response.Write("Cookie Set: test = test");
        }
        else if (cmd == "get")
        {
            ctxt.Response.Write("Cookie Value: test = " + ctxt.Request.Cookies["test"].Value);
        }
        else
        {
            // run out tests
            WebClientEx wc = new WebClientEx();

            ctxt.Response.Write("Running tests on .NET version: " + Environment.Version);
            ctxt.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            ctxt.Response.Write("Setting Cookie...");
            ctxt.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            ctxt.Response.Write("Response: " + wc.DownloadString(ctxt.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "?cmd=set"));
            ctxt.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            ctxt.Response.Write("Getting Cookie...");
            ctxt.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            ctxt.Response.Write("Response: " + wc.DownloadString(ctxt.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "?cmd=get"));
            ctxt.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

The results I get are:

> Running tests on .NET version: 2.0.50727.5456
>
> Setting Cookie...
>
> Response: Cookie Set: test = test
>
> Getting Cookie...
>
> Response: Cookie Value: test = test

Does this seem correct to you?

Comment: I am going to test that now. Probably the problem is my project settings.

Comment: Your code didn't help me at all, because it is ASP.NET code, and I have just C# for Windows. I tried to make project again and import code to it, but the result is all the same.

Comment: @Uhehesh - The reason I used ASP.NET is because I was able to implement both (a) client and (b) server in a small amount of code.  I could walk you through how to set this up on your machine if you are interested.  However I was wondering if you could provide more details as to what testing / debugging you did that makes you think this class does not work.

Comment: OK, I understand this. But as I said, I have added some code for debug, and it said that there are 0 cookies on GetWebRequest in 1.0-3.5, while it said 2 cookies (as it should be) in 4.0 and 4.5.

Comment: If you are unable to provide more details regarding how you are testing your code (maybe a sample of how you are using it) I unfortunately cannot be of more assistance.  Sorry.