# Where do I set the CookieContainer on a Service Reference?

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx, service-reference, web-reference

When adding WebService Reference to an ASMX Service on a .NET 2.0 project for example,

```
var objService = new NameSpace.groupservices();
```

there exists,

```
objService.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
```

When adding ServiceReference to an ASMX Service on a .NET 4.0 project for example,

```
var objService = new NameSpace.groupservicesSoapClient();
```

there isn't any CookieContainer property for objService

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777221/using-cookiecontainer-with-webclient-class) with no positive solution.

Could someone please guide where to find the property?

Comment: @marc_s: even for an ASMX service, he should be using "Add Service Reference".

Answer (score 16):

In contrast to ASMX Web Services that are tied to HTTP transport, WCF allows for various transport protocols to be used. Therefore, not all protocol-specific options (such as Cookies for HTTP transport) are available in a WCF service reference.

You can, however, add a message inspector that inspects the messages that are sent between client and server. This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/190806/Send-Cookies-When-Making-WCF-Service-Calls) describes a way to send cookies to the server.

I've extended the sample to use a CookieContainer. Also, the following code shows how to evaluate the `Set-Cookie` header sent by the server to add the new cookies to the container. Please note that the sample shows a basic outline, but might need extension or some more validation. However, in a simple scenario it worked.

The following snippet shows a test method of a WCF service that is hosted on IIS and integrated in the ASP.NET framework. It basically echoes the cookies sent to the server in a string and adds two new ones:

```
public string GetData(int value)
{
    var reply = string.Join(", ", 
                    from x in HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.AllKeys 
                    select x + "=" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[x].Value);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("Test", "Test123"));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("Test2", "Test1234"));
    return reply;
}
```

The following test program creates a CookieContainer for the cookies, adds a demo cookie and registers a new behavior for the endpoint of the service:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cookieCont = new CookieContainer();
        using(var svc = new TestServiceReference.TestServiceClient())
        {
            cookieCont.Add(svc.Endpoint.Address.Uri, new Cookie("TestClientCookie", "Cookie Value 123"));
            var behave = new CookieBehavior(cookieCont);
            svc.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(behave);
            var data = svc.GetData(123);
            Console.WriteLine(data);
            Console.WriteLine("---");
            foreach (Cookie x in cookieCont.GetCookies(svc.Endpoint.Address.Uri))
                Console.WriteLine(x.Name + "=" + x.Value);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The behavior serves the purpose of adding a custom message inspector and handing over the CookieContainer:

```
public class CookieBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    private CookieContainer cookieCont;

    public CookieBehavior(CookieContainer cookieCont)
    {
        this.cookieCont = cookieCont;
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint,
        System.ServiceModel.Channels
        .BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) { }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint,
        System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime behavior)
    {
        behavior.MessageInspectors.Add(new CookieMessageInspector(cookieCont));
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint,
        System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher
        .EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher) { }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint) { }
}
```

The message inspector both adds cookies when a request is sent to the server in the `BeforeSendRequest` method and retrieves the cookies that should be updated in the `AfterReceiveReply` method. Note that the `correlationState` returned by `BeforeSendRequest` is used to retrieve the Uri in the `AfterReceiveReply`:

```
public class CookieMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    private CookieContainer cookieCont;

    public CookieMessageInspector(CookieContainer cookieCont)
    {
        this.cookieCont = cookieCont;
    }

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply,
        object correlationState) 
    {
        object obj;
        if (reply.Properties.TryGetValue(HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name, out obj))
        {
            HttpResponseMessageProperty httpResponseMsg = obj as HttpResponseMessageProperty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpResponseMsg.Headers["Set-Cookie"]))
            {
                cookieCont.SetCookies((Uri)correlationState, httpResponseMsg.Headers["Set-Cookie"]);
            }
        }
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request,
        System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
    {
        object obj;
        if (request.Properties.TryGetValue(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, out obj))
        {
            HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestMsg = obj as HttpRequestMessageProperty;
            SetRequestCookies(channel, httpRequestMsg);
        }
        else
        {
            var httpRequestMsg = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            SetRequestCookies(channel, httpRequestMsg);
            request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequestMsg);
        }

        return channel.RemoteAddress.Uri;
    }

    private void SetRequestCookies(System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestMessage)
    {
        httpRequestMessage.Headers["Cookie"] = cookieCont.GetCookieHeader(channel.RemoteAddress.Uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Important to mention that this is not working if <binding allowCookies="true" /> is set as well!

Answer (score 16):

Open your app.config file and add **allowCookies="true"** to the binding.

Something like this:

```
<binding allowCookies="true" />
```

Comment: Given that the top, bounty-winning answer here is so complicated, it seems unlikely this is the answer, but at least with eTapestry's API, which requires cookies to operate, this is all it takes.

Comment: Wow...old answer but perfect.  Simplicity wins over insane complexity.  I'm working with a SOAP API (InsideSales) that requires a login which sets a session cookie for all future calls. This is all I needed.

Comment: Both the answers are best at their place. This answer applies when you need to share a cookie for all operations doing on the same Service Reference. But the bounty winning answer comes in a role when you want to share a cookie across multiple Service References.

Comment: THIS is definitely the correct answer, but it's easy to overlook on Google. So again - for keywords - if you need to maintain a session in a windows application in webservice in a .net application (equivalent to "maintain http session in SoapUI"), just enter this file and paste it there. Nothing more :-)

Comment: If you manage the cookies yourself you have to set `allowCookies="false"` as explained here:
https://megakemp.com/2009/02/06/managing-shared-cookies-in-wcf/

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution in here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx

It turns out I need a web reference instead of a service reference

Comment: Uh, no, you don't. Why do you think you do?

Comment: Agreed, Web References are just the old iteration.  Use @Markus' answer, above, instead