# Call web service and passing a cookie in an ASP.Net Web Application

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-reference

We have to call a web service hosted by our client.  We were able to add a web reference to our ASP.Net web application and use the web service.  The client just sent us a text file and said we need to pass this as a cookie to get access to the web service.  I ask for their help and they sent me this.

```
SoapHttpClientProtocol clientProxy = new T();
clientProxy.CookieContainer.Add(uri, cookie);
```

Is there a way to do this using a web reference? Or do I hav eto make a soap call?

Answer (score 1):

The web reference you have generated should be derived from `System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol` (for details see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soaphttpclientprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx)). The ancestors of this class also provide a property named `CookieContainer` so that you can use the following code:

```
webRefInstance.CookieContainer.Add(uri, cookie);
```

Comment: I had to use service reference instead of web reference, any way to do the same thing?  Tried to use CookieContainer and it does not exist.

Comment: See this answer for details on using a CookieContainer with a service reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23237303/642579