# C# getting JSON through Cloudflare protection

Tags: c#, cloudflare, ddos

FIXED - I got this to work by declaring the webclient as a static and then doing the actual call inside a using statement;  Now it works if anyone else comes across this.  The original issue was it was losing the Cookies after the initial call.

I'm trying to implement the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425973/how-can-i-get-html-from-page-with-cloudflare-ddos-portection/32426051#32426051?newreg=459f40ea6f4441999e190f0e892963cb) I don't have enough reputation to reply directly to the answer because I just signed up. Also I'm new to C# so this may be easy I hope.  I've gotten as far as changing the Regex.Match parameters based on [this script](https://github.com/Anorov/cloudflare-scrape/blob/master/cfscrape/__init__.py) but it still doesn't work. Here are the changes I made.

```
            var builder = Regex.Match(html, @"setTimeout\(function\(\){\s+(var s,t,o,p,b,r,e,a,k,i,n,g,f.+?\r?\n[\s\S]+?a\.value =.+?)\r?\n").Groups[1].Value;
            builder = Regex.Replace(builder, @"a\.value = (parseInt\(.+?\)).+", "$1");
            builder = Regex.Replace(builder, @"\s{3,}[a-z](?: = |\.).+", "");
            //Format the javascript..
            builder = Regex.Replace(builder, @"[\n\\']", "");
```

Here's how I'm calling it

```
    private static WebClient ddosclient = null;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        while (ddosclient == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Trying..");
            ddosclient = Cloudflare_Evader.CloudflareEvader.CreateBypassedWebClient("https://yobit.net");

        }
        using (ddosclient)
        {
            string tradesuri = "";
            string tradesjson = "";
            string depthjson = "";
            string depthuri = "";
            tradersuri = "https://yobit.net/api/3/trades/" + pair;
            Console.WriteLine(tradersuri);
            tradesjson = ddosclient.DownloadString(tradesuri);

            depthuri = "https://yobit.net/api/3/depth/" + pair;
            Console.WriteLine(depthuri);
            depthjson = ddosclient.DownloadString(depthuri);
        }
    }
```

Here's the code from the link,including my edits to the Regex.Match:

```
        using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections;
using System.Threading;

namespace Cloudflare_Evader
{
    public class CloudflareEvader
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Tries to return a webclient with the neccessary cookies installed to do requests for a cloudflare protected website.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="url">The page which is behind cloudflare's anti-dDoS protection</param>
        /// <returns>A WebClient object or null on failure</returns>
        public static WebClient CreateBypassedWebClient(string url)
        {
            var JSEngine = new Jint.Engine(); //Use this JavaScript engine to compute the result.

            //Download the original page
            var uri = new Uri(url);
            HttpWebRequest req =(HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0";
            //Try to make the usual request first. If this fails with a 503, the page is behind cloudflare.
            try
            {
                var res = req.GetResponse();
                string html = "";
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
                    html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return new WebClient();
            }
            catch (WebException ex) //We usually get this because of a 503 service not available.
            {
                string html = "";
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
                    html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                //If we get on the landing page, Cloudflare gives us a User-ID token with the cookie. We need to save that and use it in the next request.
                var cookie_container = new CookieContainer();
                //using a custom function because ex.Response.Cookies returns an empty set ALTHOUGH cookies were sent back.
                var initial_cookies = GetAllCookiesFromHeader(ex.Response.Headers["Set-Cookie"], uri.Host); 
                foreach (Cookie init_cookie in initial_cookies)
                    cookie_container.Add(init_cookie);

                /* solve the actual challenge with a bunch of RegEx's. Copy-Pasted from the python scrapper version.*/
                var challenge = Regex.Match(html, "name=\"jschl_vc\" value=\"(\\w+)\"").Groups[1].Value;
                var challenge_pass = Regex.Match(html, "name=\"pass\" value=\"(.+?)\"").Groups[1].Value;

                var builder = Regex.Match(html, @"setTimeout\(function\(\){\s+(var s,t,o,p,b,r,e,a,k,i,n,g,f.+?\r?\n[\s\S]+?a\.value =.+?)\r?\n").Groups[1].Value;
        builder = Regex.Replace(builder, @"a\.value = (parseInt\(.+?\)).+", "$1");
        builder = Regex.Replace(builder, @"\s{3,}[a-z](?: = |\.).+", "");
        //Format the javascript..
        builder = Regex.Replace(builder, @"[\n\\']", "");

                //Execute it. 
                long solved = long.Parse(JSEngine.Execute(builder).GetCompletionValue().ToObject().ToString());
                solved += uri.Host.Length; //add the length of the domain to it.

                Console.WriteLine("***** SOLVED CHALLENGE ******: " + solved);
                Thread.Sleep(3000); //This sleeping IS requiered or cloudflare will not give you the token!!

                //Retreive the cookies. Prepare the URL for cookie exfiltration.
                string cookie_url = string.Format("{0}://{1}/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl", uri.Scheme, uri.Host);
                var uri_builder = new UriBuilder(cookie_url);
                var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri_builder.Query);
                //Add our answers to the GET query
                query["jschl_vc"] = challenge;
                query["jschl_answer"] = solved.ToString();
                query["pass"] = challenge_pass;
                uri_builder.Query = query.ToString();

                //Create the actual request to get the security clearance cookie
                HttpWebRequest cookie_req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri_builder.Uri);
                cookie_req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                cookie_req.CookieContainer = cookie_container;
                cookie_req.Referer = url;
                cookie_req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0";
                //We assume that this request goes through well, so no try-catch
                var cookie_resp = (HttpWebResponse)cookie_req.GetResponse();
                //The response *should* contain the security clearance cookie!
                if (cookie_resp.Cookies.Count != 0) //first check if the HttpWebResponse has picked up the cookie.
                    foreach (Cookie cookie in cookie_resp.Cookies)
                        cookie_container.Add(cookie);
                else //otherwise, use the custom function again
                {
                    //the cookie we *hopefully* received here is the cloudflare security clearance token.
                    if (cookie_resp.Headers["Set-Cookie"] != null)
                    {
                        var cookies_parsed = GetAllCookiesFromHeader(cookie_resp.Headers["Set-Cookie"], uri.Host);
                        foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies_parsed)
                            cookie_container.Add(cookie);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //No security clearence? something went wrong.. return null.
                        //Console.WriteLine("MASSIVE ERROR: COULDN'T GET CLOUDFLARE CLEARANCE!");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                //Create a custom webclient with the two cookies we already acquired.
                WebClient modedWebClient = new WebClientEx(cookie_container);
                modedWebClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0");
                modedWebClient.Headers.Add("Referer", url);
                return modedWebClient;
            }
        }

        public static CookieCollection GetAllCookiesFromHeader(string strHeader, string strHost)
        {
            ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
            CookieCollection cc = new CookieCollection();
            if (strHeader != string.Empty)
            {
                al = ConvertCookieHeaderToArrayList(strHeader);
                cc = ConvertCookieArraysToCookieCollection(al, strHost);
            }
            return cc;
        }

        private static ArrayList ConvertCookieHeaderToArrayList(string strCookHeader)
        {
            strCookHeader = strCookHeader.Replace("\r", "");
            strCookHeader = strCookHeader.Replace("\n", "");
            string[] strCookTemp = strCookHeader.Split(',');
            ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
            int i = 0;
            int n = strCookTemp.Length;
            while (i < n)
            {
                if (strCookTemp[i].IndexOf("expires=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
                {
                    al.Add(strCookTemp[i] + "," + strCookTemp[i + 1]);
                    i = i + 1;
                }
                else
                    al.Add(strCookTemp[i]);
                i = i + 1;
            }
            return al;
        }

        private static CookieCollection ConvertCookieArraysToCookieCollection(ArrayList al, string strHost)
        {
            CookieCollection cc = new CookieCollection();

            int alcount = al.Count;
            string strEachCook;
            string[] strEachCookParts;
            for (int i = 0; i < alcount; i++)
            {
                strEachCook = al[i].ToString();
                strEachCookParts = strEachCook.Split(';');
                int intEachCookPartsCount = strEachCookParts.Length;
                string strCNameAndCValue = string.Empty;
                string strPNameAndPValue = string.Empty;
                string strDNameAndDValue = string.Empty;
                string[] NameValuePairTemp;
                Cookie cookTemp = new Cookie();

                for (int j = 0; j < intEachCookPartsCount; j++)
                {
                    if (j == 0)
                    {
                        strCNameAndCValue = strEachCookParts[j];
                        if (strCNameAndCValue != string.Empty)
                        {
                            int firstEqual = strCNameAndCValue.IndexOf("=");
                            string firstName = strCNameAndCValue.Substring(0, firstEqual);
                            string allValue = strCNameAndCValue.Substring(firstEqual + 1, strCNameAndCValue.Length - (firstEqual + 1));
                            cookTemp.Name = firstName;
                            cookTemp.Value = allValue;
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (strEachCookParts[j].IndexOf("path", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                    {
                        strPNameAndPValue = strEachCookParts[j];
                        if (strPNameAndPValue != string.Empty)
                        {
                            NameValuePairTemp = strPNameAndPValue.Split('=');
                            if (NameValuePairTemp[1] != string.Empty)
                                cookTemp.Path = NameValuePairTemp[1];
                            else
                                cookTemp.Path = "/";
                        }
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (strEachCookParts[j].IndexOf("domain", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                    {
                        strPNameAndPValue = strEachCookParts[j];
                        if (strPNameAndPValue != string.Empty)
                        {
                            NameValuePairTemp = strPNameAndPValue.Split('=');

                            if (NameValuePairTemp[1] != string.Empty)
                                cookTemp.Domain = NameValuePairTemp[1];
                            else
                                cookTemp.Domain = strHost;
                        }
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                if (cookTemp.Path == string.Empty)
                    cookTemp.Path = "/";
                if (cookTemp.Domain == string.Empty)
                    cookTemp.Domain = strHost;
                cc.Add(cookTemp);
            }
            return cc;
        }
    }

    public class WebClientEx : WebClient
    {
        public WebClientEx(CookieContainer container)
        {
            this.container = container;
        }

        public CookieContainer CookieContainer
        {
            get { return container; }
            set { container = value; }
        }

        private CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest r = base.GetWebRequest(address);
            var request = r as HttpWebRequest;
            if (request != null)
            {
                request.CookieContainer = container;
            }
            return r;
        }

        protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
        {
            WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request, result);
            ReadCookies(response);
            return response;
        }

        protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
        {
            WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
            ReadCookies(response);
            return response;
        }

        private void ReadCookies(WebResponse r)
        {
            var response = r as HttpWebResponse;
            if (response != null)
            {
                CookieCollection cookies = response.Cookies;
                container.Add(cookies);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post all of your question here please without requiring people to go and look at the content of the link?  For instance it's quite important to know what 'apiurl2' is, but if the author of that link changes the content then this question will no longer make any sense at all.

Comment: I edited the question with the urls instead of variables and added in the code from the link

Comment: FIXED - I got this to work by declaring the webclient as a static and then doing the actual call inside a using statement;   Of course I get it to work after spending a couple hours getting the question right