# WebClient to be able to do multiple requests

Tags: c#, multithreading, session, ssl, webclient

I am making requests to a web site that is using a SSL certificate. Therefore if I do:

```
            var webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadData("https://link1");  // 1
            webClient.DownloadData("https://link2");  // 2
```

In both scenarios I am exchanging public and private keys because webclient does not save session right?

Then I believe I need a WebClient class that is cookie aware. So I googled for that and I came up with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11523836/637142

If I use that class and do:

```
            var webClient2 = new WebClientEx(); // this class is on the link
            webClient2.DownloadData("https://link1"); // 1
            webClient2.DownloadData("https://link2"); // 2
```

Now I will not have to exchange public and private keys the second time right?

**Anyways here is my problem now** I need to be able to do:

```
            var webClient2 = new WebClientEx(); // this class is on the link
            Task.Fatory.StartNew(()=>
                webClient2.DownloadData("https://link1"); // 1
            );
            Task.Fatory.StartNew(()=>
                webClient2.DownloadData("https://link2"); // 2
            );
```

That throws an exception because `WebClient` can only download data at once. As a result I have done:

```
            Task.Fatory.StartNew(()=>
                new WebClient().DownloadData("https://link1"); // 1
            );
            Task.Fatory.StartNew(()=>
                new WebClient().DownloadData("https://link2"); // 2
            );
```

**That works but its not efficient because for every request I will be exchanging public and private keys**

PS:
Note I know very little about SSL therefore please correct me if I assume something that is wrong. Perhaps SSL does not use a session in order to maintain symmetric keys. In other words I do not understand why only the first request in the web browser is the one that takes a long time. After the first request all are fast. I assume the symmetric key is stored in the session.

Comment: `WebClient` can only make one request at a time. If you want multiple concurrent downloads, you have to use multiple `WebClient` instances.

Comment: How can I have multiple webclients use the same session?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the same session ,you can use the cookiecontainer, you can new WebclienEx(CookieContainer), every webclient instance use the same cookiecontainer to use the same session.