# Adding cookies support to WebClient class in .NET Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

How can  get php session values or how can i set cookies from c# app itself?

currently i can successfully get/post data but i need cookie support in weclient?

my code

```
        App.webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", datax);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the the exact use case you are working on, but as you are working with cookies, I recommend you start using [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) over `WebClient`. This class provides you with a  [CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The `Cookies` Property of `HttpWebRequest` would help you to send a Cookie from your client to the server, where the [HttpWebResponse.Cookies Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.cookies%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) get you the possibility to read the cookie, sent by the server.

See [Using CookieContainer with WebClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777221/using-cookiecontainer-with-webclient-class) on how to override your WebClient to gain the ability of using the CookieContainer provided by the HttpWebRequest.

A brief WebClient vs HttpWebRequest can be found on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/156610/WP-WebClient-vs-HttpWebRequest)

Comment: can i get a php session variable so server side session or client side?

Comment: WebClient wb = new WebClient();
 wb.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "somecookie"); System.Net.WebHheaderCollection does not contain a definition for Add .... i got this error

Comment: yes. this is why I advised you to use HttpWebRequest over WebClient. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer(v=vs.110).aspx for another sample. (as well as supporting frameworks)

Comment: HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://.co/login.php");
            myReq.Method = "POST";
            myReq.ContentType = "application/json";
            Stream dataStream = myReq.GetRequestStream(); i am getting getrequeststrem not found, i am using system.io and system.net whats wrong

Comment: see msdn for a sample on how to use httpWebRequest with the cookieContainer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dd920298(v=vs.105).aspx