# Does one request affects timing on a different request IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an asp.net webform that looks like:

```
public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000); // wait 10 seconds
        Response.Write("<h1>Hello world!</h1>");
    }
}
```

If two users make a request about the same time one user will have to wait 10 seconds and the other 20 right? I just opened my browser and made two requests to `http://localhost:10144/test.aspx` and one page opened in 10 seconds and the other in about 20. How can I have both users have to wait at most 10 seconds? Is it because the requests are coming from the same client?

---

### Edit

Is because I am implementing polling in order for the server to send notifications to the client. Whenever I am polling the webserver if I am making another request to the website that request will take forever. Polling is so simple to implement I will later use something else such as websockets.

### Solution

Thanks a lot for the help. Based on your comments what I will do is use a different cookie/session per request when polling. When polling I will use session A and wen making regular requests I will use session B. In other words I will have to cookieContainers when using: [Using CookieContainer with WebClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777221/using-cookiecontainer-with-webclient-class)

Comment: No, not right. Each request is potentially handled on a different pooled worker thread. They won't interact how you think. But if the requests are from the *same user*, each will have the same session ID, and ASP.NET serializes access to Session for such requests. You can change that; don't remember where...

Comment: You can test the 'real' behavior by loading the pages concurrently on two different browsers, or one instance in incognito mode.

Comment: However why a customer need to be enabled to access 10 second after the first one??it a strange requirement.....

Comment: I am implementing polling. On a separate thread I make a request to the webserver every 20 seconds. Then I wait about 10 seconds on the server to reply back. If there is another request taking place then that request will have to wait for the polling request to finish.

Comment: mmmmm curious i have to learn more about it never done before.