# Send Cookies With HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, ajax, cookies, httpwebrequest

I am attempting to log in to an Ajax chatroom in a website I often visit. I desire to create a moderation bot of sorts, but I am hung up on cookie handling. I have searched through all of the questions on this website, but all solutions seem to do exactly what I am doing, which is setting the `CookieContainer` parameter of `HttpWebRequest` to `cc`. The `CookieContainer` gets populated with data, but this data does not get sent with the `HttpWebRequest`. My code is shown below.

```
    class Program
{
    static config populated_config;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        #region config
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open("config.xml", FileMode.Open), Encoding.UTF8);
        XmlSerializer xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(config));
        populated_config = (config)xmls.Deserialize(sr);
        #endregion

        #region login

        //retrieve default cookies
        CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(populated_config.domain + "chat/");
        request.CookieContainer = cc;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        string login_info = "login=login&redirect=http%3A%2F%2F"+WebUtility.UrlEncode(populated_config.domain)+"%2Fchat%2F%3FchannelName%3DPublic&username=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(populated_config.username) + "&password=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(populated_config.password) + "&channelName=Public&lang=en&submit=Login";
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(populated_config.domain + "ucp.php?mode=login");
        request.CookieContainer = cc;
        request.Method = "POST";
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
        sw.Write(login_info);
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        string sid = findCookieValue(cc, "phpbb3_jznvi_sid");
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(populated_config.domain + "chat/?channelName=Public&sid=" + sid);
        request.CookieContainer = cc;
        request.Method = "GET";
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        #endregion
    }

    public static string findCookieValue(CookieContainer cc,string cookieName)
    {
        foreach (Cookie cookie in cc.GetCookies(new Uri(populated_config.domain)))
            if (cookie.Name == cookieName)
                return cookie.Value;
        return null;
    }
}
```

What can be done to send the cookies with the `HttpWebRequest` without manually crafting the header myself, and what am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Justin and Rajeesh's answer here: [Using CookieContainer with WebClient class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777221/using-cookiecontainer-with-webclient-class) I sent the cookies manually like this:

```
        string login_info = "login=login&redirect=http%3A%2F%2F"+WebUtility.UrlEncode(populated_config.domain)+"%2Fchat%2F%3FchannelName%3DPublic&username=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(populated_config.username) + "&password=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(populated_config.password) + "&channelName=Public&lang=en&submit=Login";
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(populated_config.domain + "ucp.php?mode=login");
        request.Method = "POST";
        //manually populate cookies
        Console.WriteLine(cc.GetCookieHeader(new Uri(populated_config.domain)));
        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie,cc.GetCookieHeader(new Uri(populated_config.domain)));
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
        sw.Write(login_info);
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```