# How do you add both a cookie name and value to a Webclient?

Tags: c#, cookies, webclient

I need to put 2 cookies in a webclient with specific names and values so not just a value and I have got the following code to add a cookie to the header with a value but I can't find a way to specify the name of the cookie

```
System.Net.WebClient HR = new System.Net.WebClient();
HR.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "Cookie1 value");
HR.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "Cookie2 value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("The Name I Wish"); // Create a cookie and give it a name
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);       // expries in one month
cookie.Value = "Some Value";                          // set value
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie); 

HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie("The Other unique Name I Wish"); // Create a cookie and give it a name
cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(20);       // expries in 20 days
cookie1.Value = "Some other value Value";                          // set value
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);
```

For Sending Cookies by name via `WebClient` you can do it by writing you own custom format as follows:

```
wb.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "cookiename=cookievalue");
```

For multiple cookies by name:

```
wb.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, 
          "cookiename1=cookievalue1;" +
          "cookiename2=cookievalue2");
```

Original answer is in here: [Multi Cookies Using WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777221/using-cookiecontainer-with-webclient-class)

Comment: that looks like server side code, OP is struggling at the client-side

Comment: But how do I implement that into the WebClient?

Comment: @DFSFOT you can do your custom format using webclient. for example: wb.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, 
              "cookiename1=cookievalue1);

Comment: @DFSFOT I edited my answer check it