# UnityWebRequest: how to get/set cookies

Tags: unity-game-engine, unitywebrequest

The links you can get on google and stackoverflow are very old ([2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777221/using-cookiecontainer-with-webclient-class)).

Between 2009 and today, a *lot* of things have been solved / improved.

So my question is: how to get/set cookies using `UnityWebRequest` with the latest Unity version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to rider, here's my working code: in the `foreach` loop you can get all the values, hence I got the `Set-Cookie` value I needed.

```
foreach (var s in www.GetResponseHeaders()) {
    Debug.Log("s=" + s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SetRequestHeader](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.SetRequestHeader.html) and [GetRequestHeader](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.GetRequestHeader.html)/[GetResponseHeader](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.GetResponseHeader.html) to set and get cookies on your WebRequest.

```cs
//the key is case sensitive
UnityWebRequest.SetRequestHeader("Cookie", "Delicious cookies");
UnityWebRequest.GetRequestHeader("Cookie");
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it **depends** on the **Plattform you are targetting with Unity**.

In **WebGL** you **cannot set the cookie** header directly, as it is **restricted for security reasons**. If you use WebGL and you need to set the Cookie header for example because you use passport.js for login reasons, then you have to build your whole project and **override** the javascript **function** that is called
`fetch(url,options);`

[Add Cookie Header for WebGL Unity Build](https://braveyourself.de/cors-xmlhttprequest-unity-webgl-rest-netzworking-build/)

In this article you can read how this is done for Unity 2021.3ff
Be aware that old Unity Versions used **XMLHttpRequest** so there is a lot of outdated information out there. fetch basically replaced the XMLHttpRequest, so you can ignore it and override fetch instead by adding this script to your html index file:

```
<skript>
 fetch = function( url,data) {
        console.log("url received: " + url);
        if (url.indexOf('https://www.replacethatwithyourserveraddress.com/') === 0 || url.indexOf('http://localhost:4000') === 0 || url.indexOf('http://127.0.0.1:4000') === 0) {
          data = {...data, ...{credentials : "include"}};
          console.log("withCredentials set to true " + JSON.stringify(data) + " url: " + url );
        }  else {
          console.log("withCredentials NOT SET for URL: " + url);
        }
        return originalfetch(url,data);
      };
</skript>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to provide an update as of today, with Unity Editor 2022.2.5f1 and `UnityWebRequest`. In short: **no intervention in JavaScript is needed at all** when one wants to send authenticated requests from Unity.

The setup is a minimal node.js (development) server, running on `http://localhost:3001`, with Express.js, with CORS configured to allow that URL. As a side note, user & password login is implemented through Passport.js.

The same server is serving static files copied from Unity WebGL build directory, and it has been configured to set the right headers on response for Gzip, WASM, etc.

The server hosts an API GET endpoint, returning some dummy data, which is only accessible when logged in, otherwise it returns a 401 Unauthorized.

When user navigates to Unity web page without logging in first, and a monobehavior attempts to send a request to the endpoint, 401 is returned. When user navigates after logging in, the same request is successful and returns the dummy data.

Unity WebGL build uses the *Minimal* WebGL template.
HTH